# Exporting to csv with vb.net, gridview1.columns.count equals 0 columns

Tags: vb.net, csv, gridview, export

I create a datatable in my code and then bind a gridview to this datatable.  My data is displayed in the gridview perfectly.  When I use a function that I found in this forum to export to csv the exported file is empty and I noticed that it showed the gridview had 0 columns. I tried to set autogenerate columns to false but this results in my gridview not showing any data and still the exporting is blank.

```
Imports System.IO

Partial Class Default3
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim dt As New Data.DataTable


    Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)
        ' Verifies that the control is rendered

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/text"
        GridView1.AllowPaging = False
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        For k As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            'add separator
            sb.Append(GridView1.Columns(k).HeaderText + ","c)
        Next
        'append new line
        sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
        For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            For k As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                'add separator
                sb.Append(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(k).Text + ","c)
            Next
            'append new line
            sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
        Next
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim ta As New dsahonorlTableAdapters.MIEMBROS1TableAdapter
        Dim ds As New dsahonorl.MIEMBROS1DataTable
        Dim r As dsahonorl.MIEMBROS1Row
        ds = ta.GetData()

        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Especialidad", GetType(String))
        Dim nombre, id, espe As String

        For Each r In ds
            nombre = r.NOMBREMIEMBRO
            espe = r.ESPECIALIDAD
            id = r.IDMIEMBRO
            dt.Rows.Add(nombre, id, espe)
        Next
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Button2_Click` you are filling `dt` with data, and binding it to `GridView1` - I'm assuming that this is the part that is working.  However, in `Button1_Click` you are rebinding `dt` to `GridView1`, but at this point `dt` will be empty.  This is because each postback to the server will have a new instance of your `Default3` page class.

You could reload `dt` in `Button1_Click`, the same as you load it in `Button2_Click`, but you may be able to get away with just not rebinding `GridView1` (sorry, not in front of Visual Studio right now, so I can't test it out), since the values in controls are posted back to the server in the view state.  i.e. Try removing these lines from `Button1_Click`:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

**UPDATE**

OK, so I was wrong, data sources are not remembered across postbacks (even though other control properties, like `TextBox.Text`, are).  Sorry about that!  So, you need to rebind your `GridView` each time, and I find it easiest to do in `Page.Load`.  You can manually save your `DataTable` in `ViewState`, or you could re-query it each time (if it's very large, `ViewState` size can get out of control).  It also seems like the `GridView` columns don't get built in time, perhaps not until it's rendered later in the pipeline.

Here's a working example, showing the binding and also using the `DataTable` for the export.

GridTest.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="GridTest.aspx.vb" Inherits="SO_GridViewCSV.GridTest" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

GridText.aspx.vb

Public Class GridTest
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            ViewState("GridViewData") = GetData()
        End If
        GridView1.DataSource = ViewState("GridViewData")
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/text"
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        Dim data = DirectCast(ViewState("GridViewData"), DataTable)
        ' Add headers
        sb.AppendLine(String.Join(","c, data.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)().Select(Function(x) x.ColumnName)))
        ' Add data rows
        For Each r As DataRow In data.Rows
            sb.AppendLine(String.Join(","c, r.ItemArray))
        Next
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetData() As DataTable
        Dim dt = New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("ColA", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("ColB", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("ColC", GetType(String))
        For i = 1 To 10
            dt.Rows.Add("A" & CStr(i), "B" & CStr(i), "C" & CStr(i))
        Next
        Return dt
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, it still doesn't work, and I also tried adding the code to build the datatable before exporting and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @user3483354 Hmm, I suppose if you re-query the database you could always use the `DataTable` to build the csv instead of the `GridView`.  I'll set up a test project to see why the `GridView` isn't remembering its data.

Comment: I have been thinking about exporting the datatable to csv, good idea, what would that look like? Thanks again,